# How extract date format from date string via jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date

I want to know is there any method that is able to extract date format from date string.

for example imagine that we have a date string like "Wed, 09/23/2015 - 20:15"

there is no doubt that this expression was a date object that is formatted to string via a format pattern.

I need a method that can tell me what is used format pattern.

Comment: what do you mean by "date format"? do you just want to get '09/23/2015/'? or do you want a date object ? Not sure what you want. and do you want to use JavaScript?

Comment: I mean for example you use "Y-M-D" to format a date to date string like "2015-10-20". now I want to give "2015-10-20" to method as a parameter and method returns "Y-M-D as format pattern

Answer (score 0):

So Date.parse() does some cool stuff, but it doesn't look like it works with your Date string. If you know it will always be in that format, you can use regex!

You still need to know what the format is yourself. In your case, you've got `DDD, MM/DD/YYYY - HH:mm` or something like that. A regex that will match that is: `\D*(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\D+(\d+):(\d+)`

So you need to run that against a string and then grab the results and put it into a new Date(). Here's a full sample:

```
var rgx = /\D*(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\D+(\d+):(\d+)/gi;
var str = "Wed, 09/23/2015 - 20:15";
var matches = rgx.exec(str);

console.log(matches);
/*
[ 'Wed, 09/23/2015 - 20:15',
  '09',
  '23',
  '2015',
  '20',
  '15',
  index: 0,
  input: 'Wed, 09/23/2015 - 20:15' ]
*/

// new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
var myDate = new Date(matches[3], matches[1], matches[2], matches[4], matches[5]);
console.log(myDate);
// Fri Oct 23 2015 20:15:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

You might be able to find a library out there that will take a random Date Format string (i.e. `DDD, MM/DD/YYYY - HH:mm`) and create a new Date object for you, but I'm always hesitant to bring in libraries like that to do something as simple as what I've done above.

Comment: you know , it is dynamic. in this example the parameter is "Wed, 09/23/2015 - 20:15" but maybe the parameter is "09/23/2015" so method must give us other date format as return value. therefor I think we can not use a constant regular expression.
What is your idea ?

Comment: You need a suite of regex expressions for the types of patterns you expect, probably. So you would match it first, and if it matches, you would then exec. The second date you gave would actually work with Date.parse(). Handling arbitrary date formats is hard and error prone, so your primary effort should be trying to lock down which date formats are allowed. If this is a user input, just provide a date picker or make them choose a format.